# Cursor in nano jumps instead of scrolling

Tags: scrolling, cursor, nano

When scrolling (by holding down the down key) in nano, the cursor does not move while the key is pressed, but once I let go of the key it jumps to where it should be.

How can I get it to move as I hold down the key?

The output of `nano -V` is:

```
GNU nano version 2.2.5 (compiled 21:04:20, Nov  3 2010)
(C) 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007,
2008, 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Email: nano@nano-editor.org    Web: http://www.nano-editor.org/
Compiled options: --enable-color --enable-extra --enable-multibuffer --enable-nanorc --enable-utf8
```

I am using the nano binary that came with Cygwin and I am running bash as my shell in [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) on Windows 7 Professional 64bit.

**Extra information:**

- I have tried using emacs and vi in the same shell and they both work fine.
- This happens when I use the arrow keys or the delete key. The backspace key works properly.
- I have tried downgrading to nano version 2.0.9 with the Cygwin installer, but the issue kept occurring.

Comment: For the record, I have tried downgrading to nano version 2.0.9 via the Cygwin installer, but that didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem after I had first installed Cygwin. The issues persisted in multiple terminal emulators. I have no idea why it happens when compiling nano from source or using Cygwin's package manager - however the [WinNT binary at get-nano.org](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/NT/nano-2.2.6.zip) seemed to be (almost) problem-free.

I downloaded it and placed it in Cygwin's `bin` folder. The scrolling issue was fixed, however I was then met with another problem. Whenever I tried to edit a file that *wasn't* relative to my current working directory (ex `./folder/asdf` vs `~/.bashrc`, `/home/username/.bashrc` etc), I'd get an error saying that the file could not be found.

I added this alias to my `~/.bashrc` file: `alias nano="~/bin/nano"`

with the contents of:  `/usr/bin/nano $(~/bin/getpath $1)`

`getpath` is a python script that I had written previously to fix a similar issue in another program, it contains the following -

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, getpass

try:
    arg = sys.argv[1]
except:
    exit()

if arg[:1] != '/':
    print arg

if arg[:1] == '/' or arg[:1] == '~':
    print '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64' + arg.replace('~', '/home/' + getpass.getuser())
```

It's a very sloppy solution, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

It is not related to nano. Most likely your telnet or terminal program or keyboard driver or network socket buffers data

Comment: what telnet ?! .

Comment: There is no telnet involved, and when I use vi the cursor works exactly as expected.

Comment: regarding your edit: if there's no telnet, there's no network socket either. If it works ok in vi it cant be the keyboard buffer or terminal program either. Did you even read the OP's question ?

Comment: There are different ways to read keyboard input. could be nano is reading blocks when vi characters...

Comment: It also works in emacs. But regarding your point, is there any way I can check this block/character thing?

Comment: Most likely you need to find the source. (or upgrade nano hoping problem goes away)

Comment: I don't think that is the reason. I can hold down the backspace key and the cursor moves as I do it, but if I hold down an arrow key or the delete key it doesn't.

Comment: Might be your antivirus or other nagware too, but since you have source for both products why don't you find the cause yourself in C code?

Comment: I don't have the source, and I really don't know C that well to be able to find the source of the problem even if I did have it.

Comment: in my case, using nano via telnet with windows client, fails, but with putty's telnet client, works. Thanks